# Texas hold'em game logic loop

Tags: game-loop, logic

Ok, so I was thinking of making a Texas Hold'em game, and I wanted to write down the game logic loop before starting. Here's what I have. Tell me if I missed anything or if anything is wrong.

1. Game sets or determines the number of players.
2. Game hands out 2 cards to each players.
3. Game takes a minimum amount of tokens from each player
4. Game lets players fold, play, or raise
5. If someone raise, the game let's other players fold or play, and then loop through the players who decided to play, but haven't put in the amount of required tokens.

- If someone goes all in and one other person accepts, then the cards
  of both players are shown.

6. Game draws 3 random cards and show it to the players.
7. Steps 4 to 5 are repeated to the player who didn't fold.
8. Game draws 1 more card and show it to the players
9. Steps 4 to 5 are repeated to the players who didn't fold.
10. Game draws 1 more card and show it to the players.
11. One player wins the lot
12. Repeat until one player is left.

Is this the correct loop? Is there anything to add or modify? Can you make this clearer?

Comment: There are some split pot rules you are missing. Point 11,there can be more than one winner. As well when for example two player go all in (one with 5 and one with 10 chips). A third person calls. The person with 5 chips has the highest cards, but he won't win the full pot. You would need to determine if the second all in or the third person gets the rest.

Comment: More than 1 winner? I have never heard of it. Does it only apply when there are 3 players? What are the exact rules?

Comment: It's called split pot for more than one winner and the other scenario is called side pot. You should be able to find more information with those search terms